# Necessary conditions for this integral to vanish.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f(s)$ is a holomorphic function of a complex variable $s$. What are the necessary requirements for $f$ such that

$\int_1^\infty f(s) \mathrm {d}s = 0$ ?

assuming that the integral is complex ?

Comment: Oviously: $f$ need to be integrable... But I guess this not what you are looking for ;-) Does $f$ fulfill some properties? Is it for example holomorphic? It may be also helpful to know, why you are interested in this question. Do you want to use it to solve a certain problem?

Comment: @tampis, indeed, $f$ satisfies all that, i guess i should have been more specific. Let me edit the post. Thanks !

Comment: There is no sensible answer to this question as stated - the only necessary condition for the integral to equal zero is that this integral equal zero. As tampis suggested, you should tell us why you care! If you know something about $f$ then it could be there's a necessary condition in terms of what you know. Or if $f$ is in some family of functions then within that family a necessary condition could be whatever. But as stated there's simply no reasonable answer possible.

Comment: It's like saying "Suppose $z$ is a complex number. What is a necessary condiition for $z=0$?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This might help:** You can calculate integrals such as $\int_1^\infty f(s) ds$ with the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem). See [this example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem#Example) for an integral of the form $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(s) ds$. This connects the value of the integral with the function's residues. By taking a certain contour you can establish certain necessary conditions for the residues of $f$ (when $f$ is nice enough so that you can use the same method as in [the mentioned example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem#Example)). You can find [in this pdf](https://people.math.gatech.edu/~cain/winter99/supplement.pdf) and in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration additional examples for this method.

Comment: Thank you very much, let me take a look at that !

Comment: @ tampis : you can nearly never integrate $\int_1^\infty f(s) ds$ with the help of the residue theorem, the exception being a branch point at $s=1$ or very special cases such as $f(1+x) = f(1-x)$

Comment: @user1952009: You might be right since I haven't calculated an integral with this method for a long time... ;-)

Comment: no but the residue theorem is for closed contours. for $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(s) ds$ it works when $\int_0^\pi f(R e^{i \theta}) R e^{i \theta} d\theta \to 0$ when $R \to \infty$, e.g. when $f(R e^{i\theta}) = o(1/R)$ so we can close the contour with $]-\infty;+\infty[$

Comment: Note that you can also use really advanced contours such as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration#Example_.28IV.29_.E2.80.93_branch_cuts

Comment: @ tampis : I know that, that's what I'm trying to explain : $\int_1^\infty f(s) ds$ is nearly never equal to some residues.

Comment: Okay, good to know ;-) Thanks for clearing it up! Since this answer seems help the OP I'll keep the answer...